# Internet connection is disabled after updating the pf.conf file

Tags: macos, network, security, firewall, pfctl

I am trying to redirect traffic on all ports to my local server by editing the pf.conf file on MacBook.

pf.conf file content:

```
#
# Default PF configuration file.
#
# This file contains the main ruleset, which gets automatically loaded
# at startup.  PF will not be automatically enabled, however.  Instead,
# each component which utilizes PF is responsible for enabling and disabling
# PF via -E and -X as documented in pfctl(8).  That will ensure that PF
# is disabled only when the last enable reference is released.
#
# Care must be taken to ensure that the main ruleset does not get flushed,
# as the nested anchors rely on the anchor point defined here. In addition,
# to the anchors loaded by this file, some system services would dynamically 
# insert anchors into the main ruleset. These anchors will be added only when
# the system service is used and would removed on termination of the service.
#
# See pf.conf(5) for syntax.
#

#
# com.apple anchor point
#
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"
nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any -> 127.0.0.1 port 12345
rdr pass inet proto udp from any to any -> 127.0.0.1 port 12345
dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*"
anchor "com.apple/*"
load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"
```

Then ran:

```
sudo pfctl -f /private/etc/pf.conf
sudo pfctl -e
```

What could cause this issue? How to fix it?

Comment: I'm not a `pf` guru, but doesn't that ruleset mean nothing can go to the internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by changing:

```
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any -> 127.0.0.1 port 12345
rdr pass inet proto udp from any to any -> 127.0.0.1 port 12345
```

To:

```
rdr on en0 inet proto tcp to any port 1:65535 -> 127.0.0.1 port 12345
```